# Null value when I tried to do a post request

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-httpclient, spring-rest

I have a template driven form, and I want to send data from the form to a server with a POST request. On the fronted side everything's look ok... I have some trouble with backend side... I think..

This is my component

```
export class CreateNewTaskComponent implements OnInit {

  task: Task;
  tasks: Task[];
  tempTask: Task;

  constructor(
    private taskService: TaskService,
    private router: Router) {
  }

  addANewTask(form) {
    console.log(form);
    this.taskService.createANewTask(form).subscribe();
    this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/tasks']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.task = new Task();
    this.taskService.getTasks().subscribe((tasks) => {
      this.tasks = tasks;
    });
  }
```

when I do console.log(form) I received this :

```
{id: "7", description: "do some Java exercises", date: "2/6/2020"}
```

service implementation

```
 createANewTask(newTask: Task): Observable<Task> {
    return this.http.post<Task>(this.appUrl + '/newTask', newTask);
  }
```

On the backend side, I have a controller in Spring and a method that add a new task

```
@PostMapping("/newTask")
@CrossOrigin
public Task addTask(Task newTask) {
    System.out.println("Task: " + newTask.toString());
    taskService.addTask(newTask);
    return newTask;
}
```

My problem is that I'm receiving a null value when I print new task.

Comment: How is `this.taskService.createANewTask` implemented?

Comment: @WandMaker I edited my post

Comment: Can you try with `@PostMapping("/newTask", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")`

Comment: Also use `public Task addTask(@RequestBody Task newTask) {`

Comment: @WandMaker I put what you said but I receive Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/newTask' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I added    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200"), but it still not working